# Data Provider for SQLite ERRORS

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2005

There was an error when trying to add a sqlite database on the server explorer. Until now, I cannot find any solution although sqlite ado.net already install in my VS2005.

The error said:

[image: SQLite error message]

Comment: Welcome to SO. The protocol around here is to put the content of your question directly into **this** post. Referring soley on a 3rd party link is bad form.

Comment: sorry for that...i'm new in this forum

Comment: Don't worry about it...no harm done.